# Mute key LED not working on Ubuntu HP 15-d5000

Tags: linux, audio, led, mute

I am using Ubuntu Linux 22.04 on HP Laptop 15-d5000.
When I press the mute key, the sound doesn't play but the integrated LED doesn't bright.
Before installing Ubuntu, in Windows 11 it worked.

I am trying to fix it adding `options snd-hda-intel model={MODEL}` to `/etc/modprobe.d/mute.conf`.
I have tried various models.

This is the output of the Audio section of lspci:

`00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)`

Alsamixer says that I am using ALC236. But in kernel.org I haven't find much information about the specific driver I should use.

Thanks in advance,
Juanjo Asensio

Comment: The audio driver has nothing to do with LED control.

Comment: All posts that I found in Internet are related to audio drivers. Have you got any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Then fill a bugreport https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Bug_Tracking

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow. There are other StarExchange sites that are better suited such as https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or even https://superuser.com/ .. but regarding the other comments, this does seem like a bug and should be reported the the Alsa bug tracker.